# Google Cloud Dataflow - Autoscaling not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a `Google Dataflow pipeline job` and its job ID is: `2018-08-17_03_35_19-3029795715446392897`

The console says that it has adjusted my autoscaling from `3` to `1000` nodes based on the current rate of progress, but the job is still saying at `3` nodes only.

I also haven't received any errors in the `Google Cloud Console` regarding quota limits, so I'm not sure why `Dataflow` isn't scaling my pipeline, despite it saying so.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an error for the quota on number of VM instances when attempting to scale to 1000 workers. According to these [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#vm_instances), that quota is a factor of your permitted CPU cores for the region. I would check your CPU quotas to see if they would permit 1000x your configured instance size. I would also check that you have enough disk and ip addresses to scale to the size of that worker pool as well.

To request additional quota, follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).

Answer (score 0):

To [autoscale your Dataflow Job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#autoscaling), be sure that you use "autoscalingAlgorithm":"THROUGHPUT_BASED".

If you use "autoscalingAlgorithm":"NONE" and numWorkers: 3 (or you don't specify numWorkers, which will default to 3), then your Dataflow Job will get stuck at 3 nodes even if it could autoscale to the max number of nodes (which is 1000 if you set maxNumWorkers to 0 or 1000).

If you don't want to use THROUGHPUT_BASED, then you will need to specify the number of workers you want on numWorkers, not on maxNumWorkers.

Also, to scale to the amount of workers you want, be sure to specify a number equal or lower to your quota, check your quota by using:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe
```